# Running Headless chrome on Vagrant Homestead using Php shell_exec

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I need to instantiate/run google chrome headless on Vagrant Homestead.

I have already installed Google Chrome on the host machine (Vagrant Homestead/VM) and I can run Google Chrome if I do SSH and execute the command from within the VM.

The problem is that I can not figure out a way to execute the same command through `shell_exec()`, `exec(`), `system()`, `passthru()`. I can issue other commands and they work properly but running.

```
exec('chrome --headless --hide-scrollbars --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu');
```

I am executing it like this, any idea or help on how to run Chrome on vagrant/VM from PHP?

**Update:**

```
exec(/usr/bin/google-chrome --headless --hide-scrollbars --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu > /dev/null &');
```

This works now. needed to enter full path and name.

Comment: Instead of using exec, you could use [this php library to manipulate chrome](https://github.com/chrome-php/headless-chromium-php) using the option `keepAlive` to keep chrome running after your php script terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following works for me without the full path:

`shell_exec("google-chrome-stable --disable-gpu --headless --remote-debugging-address=127.0.0.1 --remote-debugging-port=9222 --no-sandbox")`